# Little Big Planet levels site

Tags: little-big-planet, little-big-planet-2

I'm looking for a website that contains up-to-date information on the best user-created Little Big Planet levels so far (for both 1 and 2).  A Google search turned up a bunch of top 10 lists from 2008, and some user-created sites that were clearly just a random smattering and which didn't have many of the best levels I already know about.  Best can be defined by the site either based on the in-game stats, but or by some person with a good editorial sense for what makes a level good (like the top 10 lists from 2008).  I actually prefer the latter, since the former is fairly easy to find in-game.

Does anyone know of such a site?

Comment: Nitpick: When I read phrases like "google search turned up ... lists" "... (like the top 10 lists from 2008)" it makes me wonder really hard why no links are included in the question :-)

Comment: @Martin Are you saying I should include examples of what I've found that does NOT meet the criteria?  Since those lists were one-time things generated over 2 years ago, they aren't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Probably belongs to a meta discussion, but, yes, I'm saying. The way you phrased it sounded like they have *some* relevance but are too old and maybe incomplete. So *I* would include them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sony has setup  [LBP.me](http://lbp.me).  You can search for levels, find the most popular, most active, newest, highest rated, etc.  It supports both *LittleBigPlanet* and *LittleBigPlanet 2*.

**Update:** [Sony has posted a bunch of LittleBigPlanet resources on the Playstation.Blog.](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/01/28/littlebigplanet-community-update-resources-galore/)